# Large Square Root Symbols

Tags: symbols

Normally the `\sqrt{x}` symbol automatically scales according to `x`, so that it usually seems to be the right size.

But is there any way to manually increase the size of one instance of the `\sqrt` symbol?

This issue came up in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hfil\penalty1000\hfilneg\rule[-3pt]{#1}{0.4pt}} % nice blank underscores
\begin{document}
Fill in the blank for the following equation:
\[ 3 = \sqrt{\blank{1cm}} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: have you looked at the `\phantom` command?

Comment: I tried `\sqrt{\phantom{\sum} \blank{1cm}}`, which scales the root symbol to the right size, but still leaves an awkward space before the blank line.

Comment: If DavidCarlisle's `\strut` solution is not what you want, try `\vphatom{}` instead of `\phantom{}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps a strut is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hfil\penalty1000\hfilneg\rule[-3pt]{#1}{0.4pt}} % nice blank underscores
\begin{document}
Fill in the blank for the following equation:
\[ 3 = \sqrt{\blank{1cm}} \]
\[ 3 = \sqrt{\strut\blank{1cm}} \]
\end{document}
```

A strut is a zero width rule the height of a bracket in the current font, TeX formats tend to insert them in various places like table rows to ensure that things get an even spacing. More exactly LaTeX defines strut as

```
\def\strut{\relax\ifmmode\copy\strutbox\else\unhcopy\strutbox\fi}
```

Where `\strutbox` is (re)defined whever there is a size-changing command by the following code:

```
\setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
  \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
        \@depth.3\baselineskip
        \@width\z@}%
```

`\z@` means `0pt`.

Comment: That's great!  How does it work?

Comment: a strut is a zero width rule the height of a bracket in the current font, TeX formats tend to insert them in various places like table rows to ensure that things get an even spacing.

Comment: @doncherry strut description expanded and added

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Great, thanks! I added a bit of information about `\z@` since these macros with an `@` in them always tend to scare me a bit. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 10):

The `\phantom{<stuff>}` command places a box of horizontal width *and* vertical height equivalent to the contents `<stuff>`. It has two smaller equivalents `\hphantom` and `\vphantom` that are respectively the horizontal and vertical components of the contents *only*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hfil\penalty1000\hfilneg\rule[-3pt]{#1}{0.4pt}} % nice blank underscores
\begin{document}
Fill in the blank for the following equation:
\[ 3 = \sqrt{\blank{1cm}} \]
\[ 3 = \sqrt{\vphantom{\sum}\blank{1cm}} \]
\end{document}
```

Of course, another alternative would be to place a zero-width rule `\rule{0pt}{<height>}` of arbitrary height, which acts just like `\vphantom`, and just like a `\strut`.